# Question about proving something about subgroup

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

$G$ is a group, and $\left\{H_i|i\in I\right\}$ is family os subgroups of $G$ (I is not a matrix or something similar...)

I need to prove that $$\bigcap_{i\in I}H_i$$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Any ides?

Thank you!

Comment: Presumably you have tried just checking the defining properties of a subgroup one by one? Where did you get stuck with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very standard problem.
http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_of_subgroups_is_subgroup

Comment: Thank you!
If I wont understand something I'll ask here but thank you so much!!